# 200:General Data Error:15002:Request/Response Schema Validation Error

Tags: java, soap, upgrade, axis, jax-rpc

I have upgraded current Axis version from axis1.1.jar to axis1.4.jar. Also I have upgraded JDK from version 1.3 to 1.6.

Since I upgraded JDK version, The existing web service consumer code was giving compiler error. Which was rectified using below code.

```
    // oper.setStyle(org.apache.axis.enum.Style.RPC);
    // oper.setUse(org.apache.axis.enum.Use.ENCODED);
    oper.setStyle(org.apache.axis.constants.Style.RPC);
    oper.setUse(org.apache.axis.constants.Use.ENCODED);
```

**Problem:** I am getting below error when we consume existing web service using upgraded version of Axis1.4 and JDK1.6.

**Error:**

```
com.tdi.lh.cprm.customerlink.ServiceException: 200:General Data Error:15002:Request/Response Schema Validation Error
at com.tdi.lh.cprm.customerlink.CustomerInsuranceIdentifierFinder.find(CustomerInsuranceIdentifierFinder.java:67)
at CPRMLib.getIINumber(CPRMLib.java:1449)
at CPRMLib.main(CPRMLib.java:2060)
Caused by: 200:General Data Error:15002:Request/Response Schema Validation Error
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
```

**Note: The existing web service consumer on Axis1.1 and JDK1.3 is working with no issues.
I had resolved several other issues, However not able to overcome this one. Any help is highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

After several days of research I found the reason for above error.

***I simply regenerated the entire client web service (stubs) code using axis 1.4 jar using command***

```
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\commons-discovery-0.2.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\commons-lang-2.4.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\activation.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\axis-ant.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\axis.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\commons-configuration-1.6.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\db2jcc4.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\jaxrpc.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\mail.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\saaj.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\StockQuote\JDK16\lib\jsse.jar    
java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java https://localhost:8443/axis2/services/StockQuoteService?wsdl
```

***Note: We simply can't upgrade Axis1.1  --> to Axis 1.4. The existing code (Generated using Axis 1.1 jar earlier) needs to be regenerated using Axis 1.4 jar.***